# Connection mysqli errors

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having some problems with this page , here is the code :

```
    <?php
//login.php
session_start();
require_once("function.php");

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) //verify we've got what we need to work with
{
    /*********database_credentials.php**************/
    $mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '','hotel_vaniet'); 
    if($mysqli->errno)
        //connection wasn't made
        //handle the error here
        header("location: index.html"); //we'll just redirect for now
    /************************************************/  

    //We don't have to work about SQL injections here 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(username) AS total FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    //if the passwords in your table are hashed then you should apply the hashing and/or salts before passing it
    //they should in fact be hashed preferably with a hashing algorithm of the SHA family
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($total); //place the result (total) into this variable
    $stmt->fetch(); //fill the result variable(s) binded 

    //close all connections
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();

    //if total is equal to 1 then that means we have a match
    if((int)$total == 1)
    {
        session_regenerate_id(true); //delete old session variables
        /*********Explained below************/
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        $key = generate_key();
        $hash = hash_hmac('sha512', $_POST['password'], $key);
        $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
        $_SESSION['auth'] = hash_hmac('sha512', $key, 
                    hash_hmac('sha512', $_SESSION['user'] . 
                        (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? 
                               $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : 
                                   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), $hash));
        /************************************/

        if(!setcookie('hash', $hash, 0, '/')) //login isn't possible if user's browser doesn't accept cookies
        {
            session_regenerate_id(true);
            header("location: index.html"); //original_page would be your login page
            exit();
        }
        header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
    else
    {
        //anything else we don't care about
        header("location: index.html");
    }
}
?>
```

and I'm getting this 4 errors and I can't solve this :

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): in C:\xamp\htdocs\backend\validacredenciais.php on line 9

Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xamp\htdocs\backend\validacredenciais.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xamp\htdocs\backend\validacredenciais.php on line 17

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xamp\htdocs\backend\validacredenciais.php on line 20
```

This page it's the page that validate my login . And the major problem its some days ago that problem wasn't showing up and it is ....

Comment: Looking around, it looks like the solution might be to stop closing the connection. Worth a try.

Comment: Another thing might be that the connection is failing, you're doing a redirect but you don't exit the process, so it just continues. I wonder if that might be another issue.

Comment: Isn't the above code "login.php", while your errors are in "validacredenciais.php"?

Comment: If I read your code correctly, it looks like all passwords are stored as plain text in you DB? Don't... do.... that...

Comment: PHP doesn't like the MySQLi class for some reason. Do have have the extension installed? see output of `phpinfo();`

Comment: already resolved the problem , idk why but my xamp closed my mysql proccess because of an error